# How can I create new 'draft' object with class based UpdateView before form filling?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have a product model that has a lot of field. When user click to "Create New Product" I want create new object (just create object that it has id, seller, draft status), and show blank form. Because I want to use Ajax asyncronous upload to this object. User fills the object's other fields (like upload images) and save. Also user should be able to edit own draft products on own dashboard.

First problem: I used UpdateView, but If I override get_object method and I click "Create New Product", django calls twice this method and create two object?! I want call just one time.

Second problem: When users wants to edit draft items, they go to dashboard and edit someone. Should I create new class-based view for this or can I use same view for both operation? Maybe I can add get_or_create method to my get_object method, is It possible?

my model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Seller", default=None)
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Category Name", blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Product Title", blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=((x.value, x.name.title()) for x in Status), default=Status.TASK)
    images = models.ManyToManyField("ProductImages", blank=True, null=True)
```

my class-based view:

```
class ProductCreateViewTest(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'product/add.html'
    form_class = ProductForm
    model = Product
    success_url = get_success_url

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = Product.objects.create(seller=self.request.user, status=Status.TASK.value)
        print("new obj created:{}".format(obj))
        return obj

    def form_valid(self, form):
        product = form.save(commit=False)
        product.seller = self.request.user
        product.comission_rate = Comission.objects.get(category=product.category)
        product.save()
        self.success_url = Product.get_absolute_url(product)
        return super(ProductCreateViewTest, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: The `UpdateView` is for updating an existing object. You should not create the object in the `get_object` method. If you need a view to create an object, use the `CreateView`.

Comment: You probably want a `CreateView` for the first step (when user clicks the create product button) and use the `UpdateView` to then complete the product.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it!

Firstly I create new object with my small function and redirect to UpdateView like this:

```
def redirect_to_process(request):
    product = Product.objects.create(seller=request.user)
    form = ProductForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=product)
    print("new product:{}".format(product))
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/products/process/{}".format(product.id))
```

Secondly I display blank form (actually not blank, it has object id ;) ) with UpdateView like this:

```
class ProductCreateViewTest(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'product/add.html'
    form_class = ProductForm
    model = Product

    def form_valid(self, form):
        product = self.object
        product = form.save(commit=False)
        if not product.slug:
            product.slug = product.get_slug()
        comission_rate = Comission.objects.get(category=product.category)
        product.income = float(product.price) * (1 -float(comission_rate.rate))
        product.comission_rate = Comission.objects.get(category=product.category)
        product.save()
        self.success_url = Product.get_absolute_url(product)
        return super(ProductCreateViewTest, self).form_valid(form)
```

If my user want to edit this product, I redirect to same view (UpdateView) again.

So I don't need two class-based view! Write less code and get more done.